# How to build multiple cards with photo and name(CardHeaders) vertically to show multiple user details?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I am creating gmail addon, i have show list of users after making some http call. Possible way was to make using CardHeader in google script. Can someone help me how can i create multiple cards in single page and show my details as list? Sample Code. How can i load multiple cards in place of **newCard** in my code?

```
function getRedirect(pageId,title){
   var redirectform = CardService.newAction()
        .setFunctionName('redirectCallback')
        .setParameters({page:pageId.toString()});
    var redirectButton = CardService.newTextButton()
    .setText(title)
     .setOnClickAction(redirectform);
   return redirectButton;
}
function redirectCallback(e){
  var pageId = parseInt(e.parameters.page);
   var newCard,redirectBtn;
   if(pageId == 1){
      redirectBtn = getRedirect(2,"Next");
       newCard = CardService.newCardBuilder()
                     .setHeader(CardService.newCardHeader()
                                         .setTitle("Page2"))
                     .addSection(CardService.newCardSection()
                           .addWidget(CardService.newButtonSet()
                                 .addButton(redirectBtn))).build()
   }
    var navigate = CardService.newNavigation().pushCard(newCard);
    return CardService.newActionResponseBuilder()
                       .setNavigation(navigate).build()  
   }

   function buildAddOn() {
      var header = getHeaderSection();
      var body = getBody();
      var submitForm = CardService.newAction()
                                  .setFunctionName('openLinkCallback');
       var submitButton = CardService.newTextButton()
                                     .setText('Open Greatwork')
                                  .setOnClickAction(submitForm);
       var redirectBtn = getRedirectBtn(1,"Next");
       var mainCard = CardService
       .newCardBuilder()
       .addSection(CardService.newCardSection()
      .addWidget(CardService.newButtonSet().addButton(submitButton)))
      .addSection(CardService.newCardSection()             
      .addWidget(CardService.newButtonSet().addButton(redirectBtn)))
      .build();
  return mainCard;
}
```

Comment: Hi, are you trying to show a list of users in the card? I'm trying to understand why you want separate ones. Is there any code you can provide?

Comment: Hi, From my first page after navigating to second page i want to show list in which user picture, name and any other details required. One card can be built using `CardService.newCardBuilder().setHeader(CardService.newCardHeader().setTitle("Vinay").setImageStyle(CardService.ImageStyle.CIRCLE).setSubtitle("Software Engineer").setImageUrl("https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/856922594834079744/dE2iALXm.jpg"))`. In this way i want to show multiple cards vertically one after another with the dynamic data. How can i display them vertically one after another is my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at what you want, I would suggest you use [card navigation](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/navigation#example). The way you are setting up your individual card works well, and following the instruction in the example at that link can help you create what I feel you are working towards.

The link also provides an explanation on advanced card navigation, so that you can go through several different cards easily. [Here](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/cards) is an overview on both ways of navigating cards.

Comment: I have sees that example, in that example he explained about only single card and card navigations, i tried in the similar way but not able to add multiple cards to single page.

Comment: As per the example suggested by you, `var card = CardService.newCardBuilder()
        .setHeader(CardService.newCardHeader().setTitle(title))
        .addSection(CardService.newCardSection()
            .addWidget(buttonSet)
            .addWidget(buildPreviousAndRootButtonSet()))
        .build();` this is how he is creating the only one child. My requirement is i want to create multiple cards in same page.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to do that, but each individual card acts as a "page" for the add-on, so they are treated more like individual objects rather than a place where you can set multiple ones. For example, you can have various cards with people's info, but you can only show one at a time, you would use the navigation to see them all, there's no way to show all the information you want in a single page

Comment: You want to have all the cards (for each person, for example) in a single card and be able to scroll down and see them all, right?

Comment: `https://i.ibb.co/h1WTRg1/Screen-Shot-2019-06-26-at-5-07-28-PM.png` can you please open this link and check, i wanted to do exactly same in the second page. i was able to do it in the first page but in second page if i try the same it is giving some error

Comment: in my first page i have created multiple cards pushed it into an array and returned and it is showing as expected. When navigate to next page i am creating a card and pushing it to navigation stack using `CardService.newNavigation().pushCard(secondPage).` Here i am not able to do as i have done for first page. Can you help me with this?

Comment: I see, I saw that image in the card example page and thought that was what you wanted, but that is the example they were making there, I see in the first section of the example code, `function createNavigationCard() {...}`, that they set the template for this.

Comment: I think I see another way to do it, in [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/card-service#top_of_page) site, you can see in the examples at the top a way to use `.addSection()` to extend the cards, I think that might allow you to include more information in the card, like adding another header and content

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually as per my requirement that design can be added as only card header. if i do multiple cards and return as array i am getting this error `SubmitFormResponseMarkup has disallowed value:contextual_add_on
` any idea on this

Comment: As far as I understand, that error means the add-on is already rendering a card, so it cannot do a new one. Could you perhaps change the ways your information is stored and instead of having them as separate headers, have them as separate section under a single header?

Comment: Yes i understand what you have said, but the design i need i will get only in card header. some apps have already done that. If i use card section i cannot get same design as `https://i.ibb.co/h1WTRg1/Screen-Shot-2019-06-26-at-5-07-28-PM.png`. Help me if you know how can i put multiple cards in single page for getting my desired design

Comment: I think there is something that can help, using [CardAction](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/card-action), it allows to build buttons in the header, So it should allow you to display what you need. I have not found a way to have multiple headers in a single card

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I dont need a way to display multiple headers in single card, i just need how can i display multiple cards in single page. I am currently using Card Navigations (which you also suggested in your first reply) to navigating to next page. I want a way to display multiple cards in the second page. thats it.

Comment: Could you update your question with the code you're using to create the cards and navigate through them?

Comment: Updated the question. could you please check once?

Comment: Looking at your code, I think you can loop through your data and keep using `addWidget()` or `addSection()` to keep adding the things you want in the card, I knoe you use only one header. I do not think you can add multiple separate cards in a single instance of the card. You can follow the [documentation here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/card-section) to get a better idea of how to work with sections, but I don't see a way to have several cards together like that, either navigation or sections should be the way to proceed.

Comment: Thanks, i will definately look into it. But i have seen few gmail addons which have already done that adding multiple cards in single page. and If i return array of cards in first page i.e, in `buildAddOn()` function, then i am getting multiple cards in that page.